# In Visual Studio 2019 how can I sort the items in Solution Explorer alphabetically?

Tags: visual-studio

I have never encountered this before. The items in the solution explorer all previous versions of Visual Studio have always been sorted alphabetically automatically. I added Services and Interface folders and VS put them out of alphabetical order. I am using Visual Studio Enterprise 2019, Version 16.11.17. Thanks!

[image]